# Calling Azure function from Angular 1.6, CORS problems

Tags: angularjs, cors, azure-functions

I'm trying to call an Azure function of mine, failing:

```
$http.post(url, {data: data, headers: headers})
  .success(function (jSendResponse, status, headers) {
    console.warn("worked");
  })
  .error(function (errResponse) {
    console.warn('failed')
  });
```

`Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin '<Origin domain>' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 400.`

I have changed the CORS setting for this particular Azure function. First by specifying my exact domain. And then by adding `*` as a last entry in the list of allowed origins.

But the error message remains.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out I just can't read instructions.

When using the `*` wildcard, all other domains must be removed from the list (I can only assume that the entry I had used for my particular domain was not correct, or got routed differently through a proxy).

Comment: As you have found out, the `Access-Control-Allow_Origin` response header can take only a **single** value - either `*` or the exact value of the `Origin` request header. Any other value will cause the error you were seeing.